# Probability when possible outcomes can have more than one value

Tags: probability, random-variable

This might be a little basic but I am not versed in statistics and I do not even know what to search for helping me answer this. I have a bag with some balls of different colors in it:
2 yellow,
4 red,
5 green,
1 blue,
3 half-red/half-green,
2 half-red/half-blue. I want to know the probability of each color if I randomly take one ball out of the bag. But if I take one of those with 2 colors they count as both. I mean if I choose one red/green that count as a success for both red and green. At first, I thought I could count those with 2 colors as if I had 1 of each of its colors per ball, but I don't know if that is correct.

Comment: Why wouldn't you count that as the probability of being, say, half-red & half-blue?

Comment: Your approach is correct. The probabilities that you calculate won't add up to 1 since the two coloured balls count as both colours, that's not a problem with your calculation it's an expected result.

Comment: well, I didn't count the probability of the double colored because I was asked specifically for the probability of each color, red, yellow, and blue. Thanks for your answers guys

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do this problem. Set your information up as a table:

|  |  | Yellow | Red | Green | Blue |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Yellow | 2 | 2 |  |  |  |
| Red | 4 |  | 4 |  |  |
| Green | 5 |  |  | 5 |  |
| Blue | 1 |  |  |  | 1 |
| red/green | 3 |  | 3 | 3 |  |
| red/blue | 2 |  | 2 |  | 2 |
| --------- | ---- | --------- | ----- | ------- | ------ |
| Totals | 17 | 2 | 9 | 8 | 3 |
| --------- | ---- | --------- | ----- | ------- | ------ |

The row labels are the **balls**, while the column labels are the **events**.

So now calculate probabilities like
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\P}{\mathbb{P}}
\P(\text{Green})=\frac{8}{17}   \\
\P(\{Red\})=\frac{9}{17}
$$ and so on. Note that these probabilities sums to more than one.  Since one random selection of a ball can generate multiple outcomes, these experiment must be modeled as a multivariate random variable, say
$$ X=\left(\text{ Yellow, Red, Green, Blue }\right) $$
where each coordinate random variable is binary.

The probabilities above is then describing the four marginal distributions, and there is no requirement they should sum to one.